# How to build Powerbi report using 8 different on-premise SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

How can I create a powerbi report using 8 different on-premise SQL Servers and share it with my group of specific people? There are 8 different companies, I want to know the expected sales per year on this. Any ways in order to build this?

Comment: What's your level of experience with PowerBI and what options have you considered before this?

Comment: This sounds like a situation possibly suited to a Data Warehouse environment. Get all your data into a single database (SSIS is a good solution for this), then you only need one data source for your report.

Comment: @DimUser Thats what I thought in the first place, there are no other alternatives except importing all the data into the Data warehouse??

Comment: @Rich Benner I am an expert in creating powerbi reports, I have tried using the Powerbi Data managment gateway in order to import the data into the powerbi.com, but I later found that I cant make report using the multiple data sources, the report will be created using 1 single data source and it will not be used for creating multiple reports.

Comment: So powerbi does not support creation of reports using the multiple data sources??

Comment: PowerBI won't connect to more than one server i believe, what you could do is centralise your data (as previously recommended) or you could create views on a centralised server that join to linked servers and combine the data. Beware that your performance is going to be terrible if you take the second approach.

Comment: I've not had any trouble connecting Power BI to multiple servers and other data sources simultaneously. Not sure what limitations the others are referring to.

Comment: @AlexisOlson can you tell me how to do that?